# InfoWindow doesn't get displayed in Street View

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add a marker with a InfoWindow attached to it.
The marker is visible in both maps i.e., Street view and normal map.
But, InfoWindow only gets displayed in normal map but not when its opened in street view.

There's no error in firebug console.

The code :

```
var a = google.maps;
var b = {
    center: new a.LatLng(parseFloat(ll[0]),parseFloat(ll[1])),
    zoom: zoom,
    mapTypeId: a.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [a.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, a.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, a.MapTypeId.TERRAIN]
    },
    panControl: false,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: a.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    }
};
map = new a.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), b);

panorama = map.getStreetView();
panorama.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326));
panorama.setPov(/** @type {google.maps.StreetViewPov} */({
    heading: 270,
    pitch: 0
}));
panorama.setVisible(false);

iw = new a.InfoWindow();
a.event.addListener(map, "click", function () {
    if (iw) iw.close()
});

var g = new a.Marker({
        position: c,
        map: map,
        clickable: true,
        draggable: true,
        optimized: false,
        raiseOnDrag: false,
        zIndex: highestOrder()
    });

var description = "<h2>"+document.getElementById('marker-title').value+"</h2><br/><p style='width:200px;'>"+document.getElementById('marker-desc').value+"</p>";

a.event.addListener(g, "click", function () {
    actual = g;
    iw.setContent(description);
    if(map.getStreetView().getVisible == true) {
        iw.open(map.getStreetView(), this);
    }
    else {
        iw.open(map, this);
    }
});

a.event.addListener(g, "dragstart", function () {
    if (actual == g) iw.close();
    z_index += 1;
    g.setZIndex(highestOrder())
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test if the div is showing streetView imagery or a map use:

```
if (map.getStreetView().getVisible()) {
```

Not:

```
if(map.getStreetView().getVisible == true) {
```

(you aren't calling the method ...)

the click listener should be:

```
a.event.addListener(g, "click", function () {
  actual = g;
  if (map.getStreetView().getVisible()) {
    iw.setContent(description);
    iw.open(map.getStreetView(), this);
  } else {
    iw.setContent(description);
    iw.open(map, this);
  }
});
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_panoInfoWindow.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem was somewhere else, which got resolved by seeing your example. 

I want to ask you another thing, is it possible to put a marker in street view at some height like putting it above a table or car ? I can put it on a road or floor but not on objects.